# Make Label To HyperLink

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an Webpart there i save some values and that also saves an link to an splist.

In an another webpart in what to display the link in an label but the label dont show as an link it only show like text,so my question is should i use an label to display an link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a hyperlink?

```
  HyperLinkField hyperlink = new HyperLinkField();
  hyperlink.HeaderText = "HyperLink";
  hyperlink.NavigateUrl = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

  this.Controls.Add(hyperlink);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx

or

linbutton

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.80).aspx

**EDIT**

Im not on my work pc with sharpeoint to test any code and doing so on notepad so please bare with me if the code is slightly wrong ;)

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;

SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()

        SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
        SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;

        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            HyperLinkField hyperlink = new HyperLinkField();
            hyperlink.HeaderText = item["Column Name For URL Title"];
            hyperlink.NavigateUrl = new Uri(item["Column Name For URL"]);
            this.Controls.Add(hyperlink);
        }
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: so how do i make new uri to take the value from my column Links that i have in min list?

Comment: ok iv updated the answer im not sure if its 100% right but give it a try and let me know how it goes, It should be correct. You just need to update you list name and the column names one for the hyperlink name to display and one for the url column :)